# Macro function for printing with UB

Tags: c, macros, printf, undefined-behavior

I'm learning how to use macro functions and now faced some (most likely undefined) behavior. Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define FOO(a, b) { \
    printf("%s%s\n", #a #b); \
} \

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    { printf("%s%s\n", 1 2); } //compile error
    FOO(1, 2);                 //prints 12 with some garbage
}
```

[Demo1](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/de52506aa74762f1)

[Demo2](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e4ca0dc0438b6122)

I'm most likely experiencing UB, but digging into the [N1570](https://web.cs.dal.ca/~vlado/pl/C_Standard_2011-n1570.pdf) did not give the clear explanation of this. The closest thing to this that I found was `5.1.1.2(p4)`:

> Preprocessing directives are executed, macro invocations are expanded,
>   and _Pragma unary operator expressions are executed. **If a character sequence that matches the syntax of a universal character name is**
>   **produced by token concatenation (6.10.3.3), the behavior is undefined.**

Probably tokens `"1" "2"` were concatenated yielding UB, but I'm not sure.

Comment: "*Probably tokens "1" "2" were concatenated yielding UB*". That's right. For the frist `%s` you get an auto-concatenated `"12"`, and for the second `%s` you have nothing left, hence why you get rubbish printed for that one. Try `printf("%s%s\n", #a, #b);` with a `,` between `#a` and `#b`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FOO expands to `printf("%s%s\n", "1" "2")`. The string literals are concatenated during preprocessing, yielding `printf("%s%s\n", "12")`.

This is not a correct call to printf and UB. The relevant part in the standard is this:

> 7.21.6.1 The fprintf function
>   ...
>   2 ...  If there are insufficient arguments for the format, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: So the behavior of `printf("%s\n", "1" "2");` is well-defined? But how about the section I cited?

Comment: @SomeName Yes it is. The section you cited is completely irrelevant and random, it refers to the very special case where pre-processing token concatenation with `##` - which is an entirely different thing than string literal concatenation - produces an "universal character name" such as `\U1234`. Universal character names is an exotic rare feature that allows typing of characters in source, when not supported by the source editor. It is described in 6.4.3. It has nothing to do with your question what so ever.

Comment: _Yes, it is._ You mean that at phase `6. Adjacent string literal tokens are concatenated`?

Comment: @SomeName Yeah, `#` tokens are converted to string literals in translation phase 4, but string literal concatenation happens in translation phase 6.

Answer (score 6):

> Probably tokens "1" "2" were concatenated yielding UB, but I'm not sure.

You are correct.

"1" and "2" became "12", and went to the first `%s` in `printf()`. Then, the second `%s` has nothing to process, thus the garbage values.

The compiler warnings agree too (of course):

```
prog.cc:4:12: warning: format '%s' expects a matching 'char*' argument [-Wformat=]
    4 |     printf("%s%s\n", #a #b); \
      |            ^~~~~~~~
prog.cc:9:5: note: in expansion of macro 'FOO'
    9 |     FOO(1, 2);                 //prints 12 with some garbage
      |     ^~~
prog.cc:4:16: note: format string is defined here
    4 |     printf("%s%s\n", #a #b); \
      |               ~^
      |                |
      |                char*
```

---

In you Macro, change this:

```
printf("%s%s\n", #a #b);
```

to this:

```
printf("%s%s\n", #a, #b);
```

where the comma will do the trick, as @Blaze commented. <kbd>[Live Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ePvaTxVeukFLZACP)</kbd>

Note: For the hardcoded `printf()` call to work, you would like to make 1 and 2 strings; using a comma would not suffice. Example: `printf("%s%s\n", "1", "2");`.